# Explain Polynomes With HyperComplexs

Tags: polynomials, roots, hypercomplex-numbers

I learn some of HyperComplex, Polynomes, Tailor series ... for informatics.

I know there is no direct one-way to solve (find roots) $n$-th degree polynomial equations. We have methods.

But I know that over sedenions there are very interesting properties. I see that discriminants have forms that maybe look like some computations with hypercomplex.

Is there any way to look to polynomes throught Hyper Complex Numbers ?